# How to cut off the blank part of a font character with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am using two characters from [Zurb Foundation Icon Font 3](http://zurb.com/playground/foundation-icon-fonts-3) (the pricetag and the garbage can).  I notice they have a lot of space above and below and that is making my div taller than it needs to be.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkasson/3aokb7ky/1/).

```
<div style='font-size:20px'>Hi <i class='fi-price-tag' style='font-size: 64px'></i></div>
```

I'd like to find a way to make the span less tall.  I imagine I'd like to cut off part of the character (namely the blank spaces at the top and bottom).  I'd rather not disrupt the positioning of the character, though I can use relative positioning to fix that if I need to.

**EDIT** Changed it to reflect `div`, not `span`.

**EDIT : In part because of this issue, I switched from Zurb Icons to font-awesome.  I'll still follow this question in case anyone gets it, for the sake of anyone searching for this in the future.**

Comment: Or maybe there's a way by fixing the span's `height` and having the pricetag overflow?

Answer (score 2):

I set `line-height:0px` and manged to reduce it, 
here's the modified code

```
<div style='font-size:20px; background-color: #ddd;'>Hi <i class='fi-price-tag' style='font-size: 64px;line-height:0px'></i></div>
```

Comment: Playing with the fiddle, this isn't letting the div not include the whitespace.  I notice the line-height isn't overriding the `line-height:1` in the icon's pseudo-element. (I even tried `!important`.)

Comment: do you have a live site where I can check it out?

Comment: I updated the fiddle.  I used Firefox's inspector to determine the above.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The size of the price icon is controlled by the font size, so you just need to reduce the font to 20px like the text to make it smaller.

Comment: Actually, I want the price tag to be that particular size.

Comment: Could you give the span a minus margin?

Comment: I have corrected it and I'll add it as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correction

```
<div style='font-size:20px; background-color: #ddd; height:54px;Display:block'>Hi <i class='fi-price-tag' style='font-size: 64px;margin-top:-10px;display:inline-block'></i></div>
```